# How does this equal 10mb?

Tags: php

```
$maxFileSize = 1024 * 1024 * 10; // Max 10MB
```

In what way does **1024 x 1024 x 10** equal 10MB and what would 50 MB equal to?

Comment: Read [Megabyte or MB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Megabyte). I assume that you know multiplication.

Comment: 10mb = 10485760 bytes or (1024 * 1024 * 10) bytes

Comment: Depending on the standards used.  For SI standards, a MiB (mebibyte) is 1024x1024 bytes and a MB (megabyte) is 1000x1000 bytes.   Hard drive manufacturers use this standard, but operating systems refer to mebibytes, this is why you get a 1TB hard drive and only have ~930GiB usable.

Answer (score 17):

1 megabyte equals 1024 kilobytes, which equals 1024 bytes.

```
(1024 bytes = 1 KB) x (1024 = 1 MB) x 10 = 10 MB
```

50 MB would be:

```
(1024 bytes = 1 KB) x (1024 = 1 MB) x 50 = 50 MB
```

Answer (score 1):

If the 1024 is 1024k then that would equal 10MB.  50MB would be 1024k x 1024k x 50.